# Android onActivityResult is not being called

Tags: android, onactivityresult

This question has been raised on multiple threads but their solutions are not working for me.

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.intent"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:allowBackup="false">
    <activity android:name=".Start">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Second"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

This my Launch Class

```
package com.example.intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Start extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(this, "First Intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(this, "After Intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

This is my Second Class

```
package com.example.intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Second extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Second Intent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Now according to the code, the onActivityResult function in Start class should be called when I press the back button on Second Activity class, but its not being called since I am unable to see any Toast stating **After Intent**.

Please rectify me and provide a solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: try putting SetResult(RESULT_OK);  in your second activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace RESULT_OK in startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK); with some custom constant, a positive number. RESULT_OK is -1

Comment: Thanks.This solution works for me. It even don't need to have a setResult in second class. Although if you can please explain why RESULT_OK is not working although it seems to fit in logical chain. Thank you once again

Comment: its not working because its a negative number, what apparently isnt accepted :) Anyway that would be a misused constant, as in onActivityResult you would be comparing both requestCode and resultCode to RESULT_OK which would be quite confusing

Answer (score 0):

The method [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) isn't being called because you should set the return code in your Second Class.

The [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) says:

> When an activity exits, it can call setResult(int) to return data back
>   to its parent. **It must always supply a result code**, which can be the
>   standard results RESULT_CANCELED, RESULT_OK, or any custom values
>   starting at RESULT_FIRST_USER.

To set a result code, use the method [setResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) before the activity is being closed.

Add the following line to your second class:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK)
```

For example, you can override the method onBackPressed and put [setResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) there, like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     setResult(RESULT_OK)
     super.onBackPressed();  
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me. Although @tibbi solution works for me, without setting setResult in second class. Thanks for your consideration for this problem.